# My code keeps showing a missing key/value separator error on my dynamic block

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My code keeps showing a missing key/value separator error on my dynamic block.

Here's my code:

```
step_scaling_policy_configuration = var.step_scaling_policy == null ? null : {
  dynamic "step_adjustment" {
    for_each = {for s in var.step_scaling_policy.step_adjustment : format("%s-%s-%s", s.upper_bound, s.lower_bound, s.scaling) => s}

    content {
      metric_interval_lower_bound = step_adjustment.value.lower_bound
      metric_interval_upper_bound = step_adjustment.value.upper_bound
      scaling_adjustment = step_adjustment.value.scaling_adjustment
    }
  }
}
```

My code dynamically creates blocks named step_adjustment based on the elements present in the var.step_scaling_policy.step_adjustment list. Each block instance is populated with values extracted from the elements of the list, using the specified attribute names. The resulting dynamic block instances are collected and assigned to the step_scaling_policy_configuration variable. This is what I'm trying to do.

Here's the full error:

> Missing key/value separator: Expected an equals sign ("=") to mark the
> beginning of the attribute value

Comment: Please edit your question to include the entire error message Terraform reported. Showing the full error message helps those who are already familiar with Terraform understand exactly what problem Terraform is reporting.

Comment: `step_scaling_policy_configuration` is a block, you cannot use `=` sign with it.

Comment: Solution: don't use terraform.